# Hypothesis testing with regression models

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, cross-validation, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two regression models: a linear model with one variable, and a neural network with many. I want to test whether the neural network is better than the linear model.

I am wondering the best way to do this. I think I could do leave-one-out cross validation with a Wilcoxon signed-rank test by comparing the out-of-bag errors from each model. Would this work? Is there any literature to support this approach?

Comment: I think you may using the term out-of-bag incorrectly. Neither linear models nor neural networks typically use bagging as a feature.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to use signed ranks in your evaluation, though. k-fold cross validation will let you calculate the RMSE of the two models, which is a reasonable basis for comparison.

Comment: @mkt I suppose I mean "out of sample" rather than "out of bag"

Comment: @mkt How do I go from RMSE values to a hypothesis test?

Comment: What is the hypothesis you are trying to test?

Comment: @mkt null hypothesis: the errors from both models are the same. alternative hypothesis: the neural network produces smaller errors than the linear model

Comment: I think this is conflating the prediction & hypothesis testing frameworks. Your statement is essentially the same as saying that one model has a lower prediction error that the other. And RMSE quantifies prediction error, so comparing those values for the two models answers your question. There's no need to invoke hypothesis testing.

Comment: @mkt There will be a distribution of prediction errors from both models. I want to know if the means of these distributions differ significantly. Thus a hypothesis test. But I need to account for the fact that they are paired.

Comment: That's what RMSE *is* - root **mean** square error. You could also do MAE (mean absolute error) if you wish. This is not a hypothesis test, and you do not need to be concerned about pairing in this scenario.

Comment: @mkt if one has a RMSE of 0.2 and the other has a RMSE of 0.21, how can you conclude from that whether the first model is **significantly** better than the other? I don't think you can. You need a hypothesis test for that.

Comment: I would compare them by considering *practical* significance - is a difference of 0.01 meaningful for the problem at hand? At this point, though, I think I'll be repeating myself, so I will leave this to others to chime in on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two compare two regression models (RM) using hypothesis testing two cases need to be considered:

**Large data set S:** One can divide S into several disjoints training sets and a single test set. Each RM is trained on each training set and then tested in the test set. An analysis of variance using the quasi-F test can be performed to test if RM1 is better than RM2.

**Small data set S:** Here one must resort to k-fold cross validation. This violates one of the assumptions of classical statistical tests, the problem is namely that each instance appears in more than one set. In this case one can use the **5 x 2 CV paired t test** to compare the two RMs, this test is detailed in section 3.5 of "Approximate statistical tests for comparing supervised classification learning algorithms" by T. Diettrich. Link: https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/10.1162/089976698300017197

Another good source of information is: https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-significance-tests-for-comparing-machine-learning-algorithms/

Comment: Thanks for this reply! The 5x2cv test is for classification algorithms; how can it be adapted for use with regression?

Comment: The 5 x 2 CV method is not limited to classification, it is even the recommended method by Jason for regression in the website linked above (see the Q&As at the bottom of the website). The 5 x 2 CV method is "just" a clever way of doing cross validation so that the assumptions of the t test are valid. For the t test one can use the loss evaluated in the test set in the case of regression models.

Comment: thanks - is there a way of knowing whether the assumptions of the t test are valid for a particular problem at hand?

Comment: One can check for normality and equality of variance but the assumption that the samples are iid is not possible to check only from data, one needs to know how the experiment was made.